# serializing a list of objects into a file in java

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization

I have a list of around 20,000 object, which in turn have a very huge hierarchy. I need to dump the objects into a file, so that i can read it later anytime during my process. Now my problem is, I have worked on Java but not that much on serialization and i dont have that much of knowledge how to do that.

In this case as far as i know, i need to use both Serialization ane De-Serialization. Can anyone please help. Also i can use any new API or normal Java Serialization.

Regards.

Comment: Why do you need to dump the objects into a _file_? Can you use a DB instead?

Answer (score 11):

Look at this link http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/File-Input-Output/Objectserialization.htm
Its something like this:

```
Card3 card = new Card3(12, Card3.SPADES);
    System.out.println("Card to write is: " + card);

    try {
      FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("card.out");
      ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(out);
      oos.writeObject(card);
      oos.flush();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      System.out.println("Problem serializing: " + e);
    }

    Card3 acard = null;

    try {
      FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("card.out");
      ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(in);
      acard = (Card3) (ois.readObject());
    } catch (Exception e) {
      System.out.println("Problem serializing: " + e);
    }

    System.out.println("Card read is: " + acard);
```

Don't forget to implement Serializable interface in all class you want to save
and put modifier "transient" at all fields you don't want to save. 
(e.g. private transient List cache;)

Answer (score 5):

Rather than saving every object individually you can directly save the list of objects. I am using below code to achieve this. Although I am serializing for cloning, it should be sufficient to learn the basics.

```
public static List<EmpoyeeTO> deepCloneList( List<EmpoyeeTO> objectList) {
        try {
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(baos);
            oos.writeObject(objectList);
            oos.flush();
            ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray());
            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(bais);
            return (List<EmpoyeeTO>) ois.readObject();
        }catch(EOFException eof){
            return objectList;
        } 
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: This was exactly what I needed although for an `UnmodifiableCollection`, and this code does it straightforward. Clean, direct and easy to understand. I can't understand how it hadn't any vote as it does exactly what the title of the question stands for.

Comment: Probably, because it doesn't serialize to a File, as the title states.

Answer (score 1):

JSON is all the rage recently so you can use that. [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) is a nice api for JSON serialization/deserialization. As a bonus you get interoperability with other platforms.

If you're not affraid of xml use [JAXB](http://jaxb.dev.java.net/)

Of course you can always use binary serialization, but IMO text is easier to manage than blobs.

Answer (score 0):

I give you a sample

```
import java.io.Serializable;

public class Account implements Serializable {

    private int accountNo;
    private String custName;
    private int balance;

    /** Creates a new instance of Account    */
    public Account(int accNo, String name, int bal) {
        this.accountNo = accNo;
        this.custName = name;
        this.balance = bal;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String str = "Account No:" + this.accountNo;
        str += "\nCustomer name:" + this.custName;
        str += "\nBalance:" + this.balance;
        return str;
    }
}
```

Write and read object

```
package me.dev;

import java.io.EOFException;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class Main {

    public void writeObject(ArrayList<Object> listAccount) throws IOException {
        //Create FileOutputStream to write file
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("C:\\bank.datum");
        //Create ObjectOutputStream to write object
        ObjectOutputStream objOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
        //Write object to file
        for (Object obj : listAccount) {

            objOutputStream.writeObject(obj);
            objOutputStream.reset();
        }
        objOutputStream.close();
    }

    public ArrayList<Account> readObject() throws ClassNotFoundException, IOException {
        ArrayList<Account> listAccount = new ArrayList();
        //Create new FileInputStream object to read file
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("C:\\bank.datum");
        //Create new ObjectInputStream object to read object from file
        ObjectInputStream obj = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
        try {
            while (fis.available() != -1) {
                //Read object from file
                Account acc = (Account) obj.readObject();
                listAccount.add(acc);
            }
        } catch (EOFException ex) {
            //ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return listAccount;
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        try {
            // TODO code application logic here
            ArrayList<Object> listAcc = new ArrayList<Object>();
            listAcc.add(new Account(1, "John", 1000));
            listAcc.add(new Account(2, "Smith", 2000));
            listAcc.add(new Account(3, "Tom", 3000));
            Main main = new Main();
            main.writeObject(listAcc);
            ArrayList<Account> listAccount = main.readObject();
            System.out.println("listisze:" + listAccount.size());
            if (listAccount.size() > 0) {
                for (Account account : listAccount) {
                    System.out.println(((Account) account).toString());
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A `readObject()` method that reads an object into a local variable and then returns a `boolean` rather than the variable isn't much use. Calling `available()` isn't much use either, and specifically `available() == 0` is not a valid test for EOF. You should just loop calling `readObject()` until `EOFException` is thrown.

Comment: I've just written a simple case. I loop and print it out. readObject is my own function, not a java one. @EJP

Comment: I will say it again more clearly. A `readObject()` method that doesn't return the object that was read is completely pointless. The other objections also remain.

Comment: ok thank you :)) but I'm happy now, because I wrote it when I studied java, thank for commenting ^^.

Answer (score 0):

below is the code to write objects to file using XMLEncoder, assuming that your object implements Serializable Interface.

```
    FileOutputStream os =new FileOutputStream("c:/temp/serialized.xml");
    XMLEncoder encoder=new XMLEncoder(os);
    encoder.writeObject(objectToBeSerialized);
    encoder.close();
```

Below is the code to deserializ the Data

```
    FileInputStream is=new FileInputStream("c:/temp/serialized.xml");
    XMLDecoder decoder=new XMLDecoder(is);
    Object object=(Object)decoder.readObject(); 
    decoder.close();
```