# Java Serialization - wrapper class

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization

I keep reading about serialization.. I understand how to serialize and deserialize custom objects. But I am not able to understand the rational behind why many classes in JAVA API implement Serialize by default.

Comment: Why shouldn't they? Surely it makes sense for these classes to implement `Serializable` rather than having to write all the logic manually everytime you want to serialize an object? It doesn't *force* you to serialize them, it just makes it easy to if you need to.

Comment: 'So many' is meaningless. * Which* JDK classes implement Serializable that shouldn't, in your opinion?

Answer (score 3):

Because there are cases which require the instances of these classes to be

- [written on files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8307982/serializing-a-list-of-objects-into-a-file-in-java)
- [sent via network (or to another JVM)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17795286/pass-object-to-another-jvm-using-serialization-same-java-version-and-jars-bot)
- [represented by bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2836646/java-serializable-object-to-byte-array)

Answer (score 3):

Because you can only serialize objects that are serializable. So if you have a field of a non serializable type, this field will not be serialized

Comment: Do you meant to say a class having HAS-A relationship with a String field scenario? Ex An Emp class implementing Serializable having a field EmpName as String.When Emp is Serialized,EmpName will be serialized only because String implements Serializable

Comment: yes! if an attribute type doesn't implement serializable, it cannot be serialized

Comment: In that case,Object class can implement Serializable so that all objects in both API and custom classes will be automatically eligible for Serialization ryt??

Comment: you may read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/441196/why-java-needs-serializable-interface

Answer (score 2):

Because these classes are meant to be stored in some persistent storage or transferred via network as stream of bytes.